# Ionic Change color of item based on if statement ngStyle and ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngfor, ng-style

So I am a real beginner and I am obviously missing something.
I am creating a quiz style app and I have a list with a radio group in that loops through an array using ngfor to present the answers

The list is a list of answers and what I am trying to do is change the color of the item when they click on it, i.e. green for correct and red for incorrect.

It works but the problem is that it changes the whole list (i.e. every item, not just the item I have clicked on)

Here is my code

html

```
<button ion-item  *ngFor="let answer of question.answers; let i = index ;"  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': answerColor}"  wrap-text>

    <ion-label  class="my-label" text-wrap>{{answer.answer}}</ion-label>
    <ion-radio  (click)="selectAnswer(answer, question)" [checked]="answer.selected" [disabled]="hasAnswered"></ion-radio>

</button>
```

ts

```
    if(answer.correct){
        this.score++;
        this.answerColor = '#025c25'; //correct Green Color

    }
    else{
        this.answerColor = '#AB2020'; //Wrong Red Color
    }
    this.slides.lockSwipes(false);
```

So there are no errors it just makes the whole list green or red depending on the answer whereas I just want the item I am clicking on to change color.

I have read loads of stuff about ng-class and lots of links but cant quite get my head around it.
Apologies if this is a really dumb question or I have approached it all wrong

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you only have a single `answerColor` variable that **all** of your answers are using, instead of having one `answerColor` *per* `answer`.

If you can add a color variable to your `answer` objects and change your code to use `answer.answerColor` instead of `this.answerColor`, then the colors should work as you expect they would. In the following snippet, I have updated your logic to use `answer.answerColor`.

```
if(answer.correct){
    this.score++;
    answer.answerColor = '#025c25'; //correct Green Color
}
else{
    answer.answerColor = '#AB2020'; //Wrong Red Color
}
```

Finally, if your `answer` object is declared to be a specific type (instead of `any`), then you may need to update the type definition.

```
export interface Answer {
    correct: boolean
    selected: boolean;
    answer: string;
    color: string; // Add this line!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That makes logical sense but when you say add a color variable to your answer objects I am a bit lost. Sorry I am a very new and maybe dont have the background

Comment: I updated my answer to provide more information. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: OK thanks, I understand what you mean now. My problem was that I was just using a big JSON file without creating a model. I always wondered why models were used compared to just using the raw data, I guess this answers the question.